# Is IG-88 the droid in the background in Empire?

Tags: star-wars

When Chewbacca is getting C-3PO off the conveyor belt in Bespin, there is a Droid that looks like he's been disassembled in the background. It looks like the bounty hunter IG-88. Seems like it would be a good backstory, maybe he got there first and Boba Fett took him out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sort of.  [There were several copies of IG-88](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/IG-88_assassin_droid), but ultimately he lost all of his backup copies and uploaded his consciousness into the core of the second Death Star.  He had planned to take it over (which he actually managed to do) and then rule the Galaxy from within it.

> [It didn't go well for him.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/IG-88A)

One of those backups, [IG-88B](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/IG-88B), tracked the *Falcon* to Bespin and got destroyed by Boba Fett.

Fett killed another IG-88 ([C](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/IG-88C), I believe) over Tatooine.  He thought he'd killed D there as well, but D survived the explosion of his ship.  [D was killed by Dash Rendar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/IG-88D) a short time later, during the events of the game *Shadows of the Emprie*.

Later, IG-88A's 'body' (his original chassis, which he abandoned to move into the Death Star II) was found and reactivated, but it was completely scrubbed of his existence.  Every memory bank and every circuit were wiped.  The droid then went on to serve loyally to a number of masters, before being destroyed at the side of his final master, having refused to leave despite being in the epicenter of a potentially galaxy-slaughtering disease.  IG-88 knew he would be destroyed by the firebombing that would save the galaxy (and kill his infected master) and chose to stay.

Comment: This answer is correct. I would add a little out-of-universe info to it though, that being that Lucas was so short of props that he often re-used them. At the time the head of IG-88 was used, it was not intended as an Easter Egg, or anything important, but merely as an extra droid part for use in the background. Kevin J. Anderson ret-conned this in his story, **I Think, Therefore I Am**.